# Should I close the BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, flush, bufferedwriter

In class A, my program receives the command line by line, then creates an instance of class B according to the instruction, in the program executing each instruction in instance B,
To execute the command for the output, the following method carried out. 
`bw` was declared a member of class B.

```
@Override
 public void command (DB db) throws Exception {
  ...
  bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
  for (Item item : db) {
   bw.write("("+item.getTitle()+")");
   bw.newLine();
  }
  bw.flush();
 }
```

In fact, this did not cause any problems,
Because I thought the program should close the `BufferedWriter`, I closed it in the above method, 
the next time the method called again, There was a problem that the output no longer occurs, even though the `BufferedWriter` was not a kind of static variable.
In this situation, can I not close it ??

"make `BufferedWriter` static and close the `BufferedWriter` when the program exit" can be the solution??

Comment: Only close resources you are responsible for. You are not responsible for `System.out`, the JVM is. So do not close it. Otherwise nobody can print to `System.out` anymore.

Comment: The purpose of closing a writer/reader is to close the underlying resource stream. So `System.out` in your case. The purpose is not to "close" the writer/reader itself. In your case you should not close anything and supress the resource-leak warning.

Comment: @Zabuza Oh, I saw the question that you recommend, and your comment pointed out my refusing point! Thank you!!